# C# create programmatically page header section in crystal report

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-viewer

i want to display water mark text in crystal report whenever i'll preview the report.
for that i created new paragraph object,new field(text box) object then its inserting to crystal report from programatically using C#,

 **below is the code**

CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ISCDReportClientDocument rptClientDoc1 = cryRpt.ReportClientDocument;

```
        ISCRParagraphTextElement paragraphTextElement = new ParagraphTextElementClass();
        paragraphTextElement.Text = "TESTING";

        paragraphTextElement.Kind = CrParagraphElementKindEnum.crParagraphElementKindText;

        ParagraphElements paragraphElements = new ParagraphElementsClass();
        paragraphElements.Add(paragraphTextElement);

        Paragraph paragraph = new ParagraphClass();
        paragraph.Alignment = CrAlignmentEnum.crAlignmentHorizontalCenter;
        paragraph.ParagraphElements = paragraphElements;

        Paragraphs paragraphs = new ParagraphsClass();
        paragraphs.Add(paragraph);

        ISCRTextObject textObject = new TextObjectClass();
        textObject.Paragraphs = paragraphs;
        textObject.FontColor.Font.Bold = true;
        textObject.FontColor.Font.Size = 48;
        textObject.FontColor.Font.Italic = true;
        textObject.FontColor.Color = uint.Parse(ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Gray).ToString());
        textObject.FontColor.Font.Charset = 30;
        textObject.Height = 8000;
        textObject.Top = this.Height;
        textObject.Left = 5000;
        textObject.Width = 1500;

        textObject.Format.TextRotationAngle = CrTextRotationAngleEnum.crRotationAngleRotate90;

        ReportDefController2 reportDef = rptClientDoc1.ReportDefController;

        ReportSectionController reportSectionController = rptClientDoc1.ReportDefController.ReportSectionController;

        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section newsec;

        int index = reportDef.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections.Count;
        if (index > 0)
        {               
            newsec = reportDef.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections[index - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            index = 0;
            newsec = reportDef.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections[index];
        }
        reportDef.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections.Insert(index, newsec);

        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section sectionToAddTo = reportDef.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections[index];

        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.SectionFormat newSectionFormat = sectionToAddTo.Format;
        newSectionFormat.EnableKeepTogether = false;
        newSectionFormat.EnableSuppress = false;
        newSectionFormat.EnableUnderlaySection = true;
        reportSectionController.SetProperty(sectionToAddTo, CrReportSectionPropertyEnum.crReportSectionPropertyFormat, newSectionFormat);

        reportDef.ReportObjectController.Add(textObject, sectionToAddTo, 0);
```

here issue is **new section in PageHeader** is copy of **previous section in PageHeader**,if i change **new section in PageHeader properties** it also changing **previous section in PageHeader** ,please help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
    int index = reportDef.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections.Count;
    if (index > 0)
    {               
        newsec = reportDef.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections[index - 1].Clone();
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0;
        newsec = reportDef.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections[index].Clone();
    }
```

This will create new copy of "previous section" and all changes to newsec will not affect to prev. section. As alternative you can also check **CopyTo()** method.